# Middleman’s link_to helper for localized templates

Tags: middleman

For the site I'm building with Middleman, I am localizing entire templates as described in the docs on the bottom of the ["Localization" section](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/). So the relevant part of the file tree looks like this:

```
/localizable
     |
     |- index.en.html.haml
     |- index.ru.html.haml
     |- about.en.html.haml
     |- about.ru.html.haml
```

I can link from the index.en page to the about.en page using the path helper like so:

```
= link_to 'about me', '/about.html'
```

But when I try to do a similar trick to create a link from the index.ru page to the about.ru page:

```
= link_to 'some russian text', '/russian/about.html'
```

the helper doesn't work. It ignores the `/russian` folder and creates a link to /about.html in root.

Am I missing something or is the path helper unusable for localized templates? Is the only option to use the `<a>` tag directly?

============

**Update1**: relevant parts of my config.ru file:

```
set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'

set :js_dir, 'javascripts'

set :images_dir, 'images'

activate :relative_assets
set :relative_links, true

activate :i18n, :langs => [:en, :ru], :lang_map => { :en => :english, :ru => :russian }

activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.prefix = "blog"
  blog.paginate = true
end

# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  # For example, change the Compass output style for deployment
  # activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  # activate :minify_javascript

  # Enable cache buster
  # activate :asset_hash

  # Use relative URLs
  # activate :relative_assets

  # Or use a different image path
  # set :http_prefix, "/Content/images/"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant really say what is the problem without seeing your *config.rb* file and the structure of your file system.

My guess on your problem would be like [this here](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/628)

or it could be real simple that you have to change *'russian'* to *'ru'*, since that is in file name.

Here is a [good example](http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/07/use-middleman-to-write.html)

EDIT:

Now with your config.rb , I can see you are using :en as default and :ru as russian

Since you are using :en as default(non prefixed), you dont have to map that. or if you want that to be mapped and not be default you might have to use ':mount_at_root => false' with activate 'activate :i18n,'

Try the following solution

```
activate :i18n, :langs => [:en,:ru], :lang_map => {:ru => :russian}
```

Like I said, I simply just removed :en mapping and it worked on my test. Since you make :en as default you dont have to map it. If you want both languages to be mapped correctly then use the following

```
activate :i18n, :mount_at_root => false, :langs => [:en,:ru], :lang_map => {:en => :english ,:ru => :russian}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response — it took me a while to get back to this project. I updated my question to include the relevant informtation from my config.ru file. Unlike the problem described in your first link, `:i18n` gets activated before `build`.

Comment: Changing `= link_to 'about me', '/about.html'` to `= link_to 'about me', '/#{I18n.locale}/about.html'` as suggested in your second link almost works... Only the path this produces is '/ru/about.html', whereas I remapped 'ru' to 'russian', so the produced url is invalid. What I need to generate is '/russian/about.html'.

Comment: Ok, I did some tests and know why your config isnt working, I can make an edit for the answer, but not sure why your current config doesnt work, might be a bug, or weird interactions because we have a default prefixing.

Comment: Hmm, I removed the default English language from the language map like you said, and restarted the middleman server, but the `link_to` helper in the index.ru.html.haml file (`= link_to 'about me', '/about.html'`) still generates a link to the English version of the page :-( Could you share how you created links to pages in different locales in your erb/haml files?

Comment: I even got the impression [from GitHub](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1306#issuecomment-48199696) that what I am trying to do with the `link_to` helper isn't possible...

Comment: <% link_to "/#{I18n.locale.to_s + "/" if I18n.locale == :ru}terms" do %>
  <%= t("footer.terms_text") %>
<% end %>

Might help someone?